# Iptables port forwarding chain on VPN network on Debian

Tags: debian, iptables

I have problem with setup of my network. It almost works... but not totally:)

I want to have access to the camera in the building on the countryside. I have access to the Internet with no public IP, so I decided to create VPN. In the countryside house I have one RaspberryPI (VPN client) and LTE router (Huawei B315) connected together with IP camera. In my house, where I have modem with public IP I have another RPI (VPN server). VPN is in routing mode (RPIs creates separate network).

So to sum up:

1. Gateway - modem at my house
2. RPI1 - VPN server connetcted to modem at my house (IP: eth0-192.168.0.6 (local network), tun0-10.8.0.1 (VPN network))
3. PRI2 - VPN client connected to modem in the other house 
   (IP: eth0-192.168.0.100, tun0-10.8.0.2)
4. Camera - Planet ICA-4150 (with active-x web interface) - connected to modem in the other house
   (IP: 192.168.0.10)

VPN works - I can ping both RPIs from each other and I can ssh from my house to RPI1 and then to RPI2.

I want to be able to open camera's web interface like this:
example.ddns.net:9000. DDNS is set up, and it works.

On my house's modem I forwarded port 9000 from outside to local IP 192.168.0.6:9000 (RPI1).

My iptables settings:
RPI1:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:9000
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p udp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:9000
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.8.0.2 --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -d 10.8.0.2 --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

RPI2:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.10:80
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p udp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.10:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.0.10 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -d 192.168.0.10 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

When I type proper address in browser, I can see web interface, but cannot log in. Of course I can log in, when my laptop is connected locally with camera. And I also made experiment, that I connected camera to LAN in my house, and exported one port in my house's modem directly to the camera, and this also works, but only if I redirect both TCP and UDP ports.
I also cannot log in, when I type 192.168.0.6:9000 in browser from my house local network.

I also tried changin port 9000 to 24000, with no luck.

Does anyone has any idea on what I am doing wrong? Maybe I missed something in iptables?

Answer (score 0):

This I think is because you GET the webpage on 9000 port on your browser but the camera which hosts the server sees req on port 80. So the post action if it puts an absolute URL will be sent to port 80. You can check this on the networks tab of your browser. If that's the case add a iptable dnat for the destination IP and dport 80

Comment: Thanks. I didn't fully understood your answer, and you inspired me to do some tests with Wireshark (network tab on browser showed nothing). It turned out, that this camera also uses two other ports for some communication, that active-x app does. Exporting this ports makes it work.